# Can we have newer versions of third-party libraries in the Stack Snippets tool?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

The latest available version of jQuery in the snippet editor is 2.1.1. This was released mid 2014! We're currently on version 2.2.4 and even jQuery 3 is out now with the first patch levels. Or another example, AngularJS. The latest version that can be chosen in the editor is from 2014 too and there is no single version of Angular 2 available.

Could the Stack Overflow team please update this with newer versions of these libraries? (as well as the other libraries if there are newer versions)

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ. I've noted this in my last sentence in my post. ;) But as I said, this is not how it should be. It would be nice to easily provide answers. Not only for me, I think there would be people outside, dropping a maybe good answer because they are too lazy to do this kind of stuff manually, or use tools like `jsfiddle` instead. It would be better for all to have a good maintained editor here on SO.

Comment: Asking "Why is the snippet editor not gonna be updated/extended anymore?" implies that someone has *already decided* it won't be updated. Otherwise, you should ask "Is the snippet editor going to be updated?"

Comment: Well, actually I'm not knowing, if there was an update in the past. But as the editor has no new libraries since 2014, I would assume it is at least not well maintained. And in about two years I think it is okay to ask, if it's *not gonna be updated anymore*. @Louis

Comment: Why is this question getting so many downvotes now? I thought this is what `meta` is for? Did I asked the wrong thing? Or did I anything else wrong here? At least leave a comments then ...

Comment: On a feature request down votes mean: No, don't implement this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what is the point for this? I mean, what is so bad on newer libraries? It should be pretty easy to add too. And specially for libs with new behaviors, like jQuery 3 has, it would be pretty useful for examples. @rene

Comment: I didn't even realize this was tagged as a feature-request. Does that make sense here? The OP doesn't seem to be requesting a feature as much as asking for info on an existing one.

Comment: sure, the 15 minutes it takes to implement this one, there are 3 other bugs  of 5 minutes that remain unfixed.

Comment: I had to choose one tag. And `feature-request` seems the best for me. But feel free to edit. @BSMP

Comment: Well I can't, personally, as I'm still under 2K.

Comment: Maybe there is more traction to get the editor open-sourced so anyone can PR on that. But I recall that has been asked before and would still take serious dev time to get that going.

Comment: Maybe @rene. But then the intention of keeping things on SO gets lost. It would be easier to use other resources then. And you will not really tell me that the biggest developmer help-site on the net don't have the time for adding such things?!

Comment: Last update on Stack Snippet was in [June](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Comment: @eisbehr Yes, they don't have the time to add things to a piece of code that is not used by everyone and has a reasonable workaround

Comment: Thats really sad. I will leave this here for now. But personally I will go back to jsfiddle then. Who knows what will be abadon next on these tools here ...

Comment: also relevant (MSE): [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Comment: *Who knows what will be abadon next* I agree with Louis that it's confusing for you to keep insisting someone's already decided not to support this, especially after rene pointed out that it was updated in June.

Comment: Maybe the tool itself has been updated in Jun, but the libraries could be called *abadoned*. We're talking about a very long time. Development and IT in general are so fast living, that this is a huge impact imo. It's not only jQuery, the other libs aren't updated too. There is no version of Angular 2, and the last version of Angular 1 is even out of 2014. So call it as you like and say the editor has become an *update*, but there is nothing really *up-to-date*. @BSMP

Comment: I don't really get it. You're complaining that they haven't updated the version of jQuery used by the snippet editor? Who cares? What's the motivation for upgrading? Are there critical bugs that need to be fixed? Or is there some other feature that you're requesting? Updating the version of a library *just to be doing it* doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you really asking if jQuery 3 or Angular 2 has become new features / behaviors in it's mayor releases since jQuery 1/2 or Angular 1? Then it would be shocking for you to hear, but yes: there **are** new and changed things! What do you think new version would be for? Just to have fancy new numbers? I'm not complaining about each patch level. @CodyGray

Comment: @CodyGray That's referring to the options *in* the editor. That's somewhat unclear, I'll edit it.

Comment: Can I use TypeScript in snippets?

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for the hint. But that is not realted. A `latest` option is a bad idea and that is not what I am looking for. I just want newer versions, but they should be fixed.

Comment: @eisbehr Have you tried http://plnkr.co?

Comment: @guest271314 Thats not the point. I could use jsfiddle too. But it would be way better to have the examples here on SO and not on an external side.

Comment: @eisbehr You should still be able to include link to specific version of jQuery or other library at stacksnippets. Or, create a piece which achieves the same, save at,  for example, a gist, and load it at each of your stacksnippets?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, sure. You can do many things manually. But I don't want to take research first to find a CDN where these things are hosted in the correct versions, to post an answer. It should be fast and easy. And I think there would be many more people thinking like this. And the functionality is already there, there is only a update of the versions needed, not more. Should be pretty easy to extend.

Comment: @eisbehr Which version of jQuery do you want to load?

Comment: @guest271314 Read my question again please. It's not abaout specific versions.

Comment: @eisbehr Yes, gather Question. Though note, fwiw, you could implement this feature for your own stacksnippets `$(".snippet-holder #snpte-jquery-select").prepend("<option value='3.0.0'>3.0.0</option>")`

Comment: @guest271314 Sure, I could. But then only me have this available. Everybody else can't still use it. (*we should probably stop to spam the comments here*)

Comment: Do not do spam. Agree with you. Cheers

Comment: What about this question? Why jquery version didn't update to, for example,  3.2.1?

Comment: @guest271314 Is there a workaround for angular? if so, can you put that in an answer?

Comment: Really could use Angular in the editor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've updated the versions for all listed libraries to reflect recent versions available on cdnjs as of November 16th 2018. This also involved switching to cdnjs as the host for jQuery and Angular.js, both of which were previously hosted on Google's cdn.

As part of this, I've restructured the backend a bit; it should be a bit easier to update the version lists in the future. We could even pull versions automatically from the cdnjs API if need-be... However, we may wish to consider an alternative approach: as BradleyDotNet noted, the current setup makes using platforms like the newer Angular prohibitively difficult; if we ever want to see folks using snippets for such platforms, we'll need to look at providing something closer to saved templates rather than relying on the simple script tag insertions which we currently use.

Comment: Hi, Any chance of getting jQuery 3.7.0 into the snippet editor?

Comment: If you can find someone left on the engineering team to update the list, @mplungjan - I would suggest raising a new issue for visibility

Answer (score 9):

The problem, as I see it, is that there is no standard place to get informed of what versions of which libraries are available on CDNs. There are some out there that get close:

- [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/) has [an API for querying the libraries it hosts](https://cdnjs.com/api), but they don't have, for example, Angular.
- [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) has [a similar API](https://github.com/jsdelivr/data.jsdelivr.com), and appears to be able to serve libraries that are available on NPM & GitHub.

Using an API like those above would, of course, only solve the issue of getting a relatively up-to-date list of versions for the libraries/packages one wishes to support - that's not always an easy decision to make. For instance, Angular is not a monolithic library; you have to chose which modules to include. Choosing which libraries to populate versions for is a different question (and answer).

Comment: Who needs Angular anyways?

Comment: @TinyGiant Lots of people, including me :). Granted, Angular in stack snippets sounds... hard. There's a lot that goes into that.

Comment: @Bradley I was being facetious.

Comment: It should be a matter of regular updates, not waiting for notifications from elsewhere. jQuery is absurdly out of date still.

Comment: @isherwood You're probably better off writing a new [feature-request] than commenting on a fellow user's answer. Even Shog doesn't work there any more. My answer here was a suggestion to make it easier on SO employees (and users) so that we wouldn't have to keep requesting new versions; it would be automatic.

Comment: It was intended as a response to your answer. This isn't my first rodeo. :) Maybe I misunderstood your position on the issue.