# Update CDN resources

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

The CDN options in the select (left-hand) from were we can pick up a resource reference when making a a snippet are very outdated.

For instance: AngularJS (one of the most I use) contains from version 1.0.1 to **1.2.23** when the current version of this framework is above **1.6**.

The same happens with many others (not to say all of them).

It is worth to say I found this question ([Update d3.js reference in snippet's "options"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341085/update-d3-js-reference-in-snippets-options), asked 1 year and 1 month ago) which practically addresses the same problem and for which there is no current answer.

So I was wondering... is there any possibility to update these resources  and make us easier to create snippets with updated values (as it is required for many answer to be correct).

[image]

Comment: yea, Its too old

Comment: What would happen if all those versions where removed and you only get a version template where you have to supply the correct number yourself? You can have a couple of templates if you like for supporting multiple cdn's or if the version strategy changed or so. That requires less SE dev time to update all the libs over and over again.

Comment: @rene that would be great! It would save us both (SE devs and users) valuable time.

Comment: Feel free to post a feature request for that. I'm not using the stack snippets and its libraries selection that often so If I post it I'll probably get busted for not knowing what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think a user-entered version will be __very__ susceptible for errors. Ideally, the list would just be updated automatically, by getting said library's version history. This would require some dev time to write something to obtain / parse the list, but it (mostly) removes the human factor.

Comment: Same without answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333042/can-we-have-newer-versions-of-third-party-libraries-in-the-stack-snippets-tool