# Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, status-review, stack-snippets

Please update the version of [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) used by Stack Snippets (and update the available versions of other scripts in the drop-down lists; ideally, update that list automatically). It's currently 6.10.3, which doesn't understand `async` functions. The current version is 7.10.13 (`https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js`). Or you can link to the latest via `https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js`.

Here's an example of a snippet that should work, but fails because the old version doesn't transpile `async` functions:

```js
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args));
}
async function foo() {
    await delay(20);
    return "Hi";
}
foo()
.then(msg => {
    console.log(msg);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Here it is using the current version of Babel Standalone:

```html
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-3">
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args));
}
async function foo() {
    await delay(20);
    return "Hi";
}
foo()
.then(msg => {
    console.log(msg);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.2/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this will also mean providing `data-*` attributes on the generated `type="text/babel"` script element so Babel knows what to do. It's probably best to allow the user to pick those. Also, note it will need to have the option to include `regenerator-runtime` (`core-js` probably would make sense as well) in case the transpiled code needs polyfills.

Aside from Babel...

Similarly the versions of React and other tools are well out of date. React tops out at 16.6.3 in the list, but the current version is 16.13.1 and there's a major feature (hooks) that isn't in the old version.

Some kind of regular review of versions, or just automatically drawing a feed from `cdnjs.com`, would make sense rather than the community having to drive this process.

---

**##Bump## February 5th 2022:** This is ***still*** broken nearly **two and a half years later** *("bumping" because I can't bounty the question for some reason)*. It impacted someone trying to get help yet again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923727/using-setstate-in-async-function-with-parameters-used-for-onclick). And again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997784/react-infinite-loop-onclick-inside-a-render-calls-setstate). **Please fix this.**

Comment: It doesn't look like the new version transpiles them either - Inspect the snippet and look at the Babel-generated `<script>` (with a `sourceMappingURL`) at the bottom of the `<head>`. The `async function foo` is still there - but, at least in the new version, it doesn't *refuse to transpile* due to the `async` keyword, which is more than can be said for the old version. Transpiling `async` functions requires a *whole lot* of extra code

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Well spotted!! It probably needs some configuration or something telling it what environment to target... But then, why would it transpile the rest parameter? Nothing has `async` functions but not rest... Hmmm...

Comment: Perhaps because transpiling *most* syntax (including rest parameters) is relatively easy, but transpiling `async` (to ES5, at least) is [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347026/what-is-the-potential-drawback-of-using-async-functions-everywhere/51347160#51347160) and [buggy](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+async), so they want you to explicitly specify if you want to do so

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Fixed it. Apparently config is via `data-` attributes on the `script` tag. I've added the ones jsFiddle uses.

Comment: ...but the fix isn't right either, it targets ES2017 and so doesn't transpile ES2016-ES2017 stuff (like `const`). Changing it to ES2015 requires loading the regenerator runtime...blech.

Comment: Fixed it. This is a *slight* bigger request than just updating the version (though just updating the version is a start).

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Re your "buggy" link, the less misleading version would be [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22i%3A+bug%22++async). And yes, it is hard. :-) But I don't think that's why it wasn't transpiling the `async`, it was just lack of configuration.

Comment: Glad you put "(and others)". One of the only problems I have with Stack Snippets are the rarely-updated versions of libraries. I know we had [a FR for new versions a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333042/215552), but nothing since then.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Hmmm. I wonder if the above should be [tag:feature-request] instead of [tag:support]...

Comment: Yup, `async` / `await` is *just* syntactic sugar ... ;)

Comment: Stack Exchange takes security very seriously... So much so it frequently runs with out of date components...

Comment: @jww We're already able to chuck whatever malicious code we like into a snippet. An out-of-date snippets-specific library version doesn't expose Stack Overflow or its users to any new security threat beyond those that are inherent in the snippets feature existing. They should upgrade it because having the latest version would be useful to users, but there's absolutely no security benefit to doing so.

Comment: What is this "Babel Standalone" that you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - The [in-browser version of Babel](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation).

Comment: @Makyen - And yes, I'm **very** frustrated, with **very** good cause. I trip over the rubbish nature of Stack Snippets every day when trying to help people. It's disgraceful, frankly, that SO hasn't done better here. But frustration is not why I made that edit. :-) That said, I firmly disagree that something being flat-out broken (`async` fails in JSX questions) isn't a bug.

Comment: I understand you're frustrated, but "bumping" your post with an edit *isn't permitted*, so please don't do that. I know you're frustrated by the situation. Unfortunately, there isn't all that much we can do to get them to speed up handling it.

Comment: Thanks for all that @Makyen, much appreciated. Linking to instances isn't *primarily* to bump, but it is (or was) *partially* to bump. I wanted to start documenting it (anecdotally and haphazardly, granted) when it caused trouble, as it increasingly is because people are increasingly using `async` functions. The goal being to show impact and hopefully get it bumped up (no pun!) in the priorities, esp. since -- as you say -- it should be so easy to fix. I guess I could do that in the comments, but documenting impact seems relevant to the question itself, not ephemeral...

Comment: ...comments. So I'd rather keep listing them in the question, perhaps without the "bump" text. And frankly, I have to admit I **want** people to be tired of seeing it on the list, because some of those people may be in a position to **finally** do something about it.

Comment: The real-world impact of Stack Snippets being so poor (not just in this regard) is increasing. More and more questions get posted with virtually no code (just enough to get past the check) and a link to CodeSandbox/CodePen/StackBlitz/etc. And worse, these questions get answered without being fixed; people just go offsite, see what's wrong, and then post an answer. That Q&A is useless to people for whom the off-site resource is blocked, or if it disappears, etc.; and often, they would have been duplicates if people could have seen the code to vote accordingly. When I raise the issue...

Comment: ...I often get complaints about how bad Snippets are vs. those other resources, and I get it -- they're primitive by the standards of five years ago, much less today. The fact that spending an hour or two doing some basic fixes -- or perhaps a week doing an integration w/something modern, perhaps something that serves other languages/environments as well -- is lower priority than the nonsense they're spending time on frankly beggars belief. And has me seriously considering just giving up on SO entirely.

Comment: @Makyen - Separately, please reconsider [tag:bug] for this. The Stack Snippets editor shows an input area labelled "JavaScript." If I put valid JavaScript code in that box (`async` was in ES2017, **five years ago** in June) when the Babel checkbox is ticked, the snippet fails. That's a bug. It's something not working as intended. (And note that being put in the spec doesn't happen until **after** there are multiple conforming implementations in the field. Most browsers natively supported `async` **more** than five years ago.)

Comment: `async` and `await` work *just fine* in snippets, if you're using actual JavaScript and the browser's native processing. The checkbox labeled "BabelJS / ES2015" *does exactly what its label says it does*. The `async` and `await` keywords were added as of ES2017. What you're asking for is new/additional functionality. I don't see how that's a bug report, rather than a feature request. As far as I know, it makes no functional difference as to if this is tagged as a [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request], so which one to use is merely a philosophical difference of opinion as to what a "bug" is.

Comment: @Makyen - I strongly disagree, but if it makes no difference, fine (though that argues both ways you realize). This is definitely **not** new functionality. It's also basic maintenance. The site is using a **years**-out-of-date tool that's easily updated to something current, and it's impacting users (the React tag is a **big deal** on SO at present, and 99.99999% of code using React uses JSX, which needs Babel to transform it). If there's anything you can do to raise the visibility, that would be really great. We've spent more time discussing it than it would have taken someone to fix it.

Comment: If the checkbox was labeled just "BabelJS", then not using the latest version of BabelJS would reasonably be considered a bug. However, it's labeled as "BabelJS / **ES2015**", which *explicitly* says that it's limited to ES2015. Thus, it's *doing exactly what it says it does*. Frankly, I'd consider it a bug if a checkbox labeled "BabelJS / ES2015" was using the latest version and supporting ES2017 features, because then it would be doing something other than what it says it does. That we all wish it was something other than what it is, doesn't make it a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I consider it *very* unfortunate, frustrating, etc. that the amount of time we spend on meta discussing this type of change *far* outweighs the amount of time it would take to actually fix it. IMO, SE would be *dramatically* better off (quality/features/cost/etc.) with a large part of their code-base being public and available for others to suggest changes/PRs, even if the license they use doesn't allow it to be used by other people (i.e. public, but not open source). This is particularly true of all the JS/CSS which is always *effectively* public anyway.

Comment: @Makyen - *"SE would be dramatically better off (quality/features/cost/etc.) with a large part of their code-base being public and available for others to suggest changes/PRs"* Amen to that. You'd think they'd know that, given the fact that Stack Snippets were more than half written by @​canon, not to mention all the userscripts out there. But by all means, let's [rearrange the domain deck chairs into something that looks like a phishing site instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962/157247), because *that's* important. :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I share your frustration. It's clearly a bug _in an existing feature_. SO has a) dropped support for all but the most recent versions of Edge/Chrome/FF but b) seem to not be able to support _those_ browsers properly either.

Comment: _"The system is operating as designed/intended._": back in 2015. FYI Codemirror also hasn't been upgraded since 2017.