# Why won't this snippet with async await work here on Stack Overflow snippet editor?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Why won't the following snippet work here on Stack Overflow?

I'm trying to add some example of basic async/await and returned promises.

This exact same piece of code works just fine on my development environment. I'm using [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), but I've seen snippets with async await functions here on Stack Overflow before.

What's happening?

It gives the error:

```
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
```

```js
function bar() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      resolve('resolved after 1500ms');
    },1500);
    // return resolve('resolved');
  });
}

async function foo() {
  const result = await bar();
  console.log(result);
}

foo();
```

I'm on Chrome version 75.0.3770.80 (official build) (64-bit).

Comment: Which browser gives you such a poor error message? FF shows "_SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token_ ..."

Comment: I'm on Chrome Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: This bug still causes [ongoing trouble for people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437407/why-does-manually-including-babel-cause-this-snippet-to-stop-working).

Comment: [Bugs will not be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369893/performance-delay-in-editor-when-moving-to-a-blank-line).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a Stack Snippets bug (but SE won't call it a bug, they call it a "feature request"), please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets).

The problem is that the version of babel-standalone used by Stack Snippets is (well) out of date and doesn't understand `async`/`await`. Amusingly, on any modern browser, if you **un**tick the Babel box in the snippet, it'll work. But if you want JSX compilation, you need to tick the box, so using `async` in (say) a React question won't work.

It also works if you use a current version of babel-standalone, like this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
function bar() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      resolve('resolved after 1500ms');
    },1500);
    // return resolve('resolved');
  });
}

async function foo() {
  const result = await bar();
  console.log(result);
}

foo();
</script>
```

Note that you can't put the code that Babel will process in the JavaScript panel in the snippet editor. You have to put it in the HTML panel instead, in a `<script type="text/babel">...</script>` tag.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - Thanks for updating the version. FWIW, it doesn't matter where the Babel script is. It uses a `DOMContentLoaded` handler to look for scripts to handle. For me it made more sense to put it at the end, but it doesn't matter. :-)

Comment: In most cases the external scripts will be at the top of the snippet, so I thought it would be better located at the top. But it indeed doesn't really matter if it's at the top or bottom.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - Yeah. Putting scripts at the top is a bit of an anti-pattern, I wish the snippet editor didn't do that. :-) (But they've always ignored my offers to improve Stack Snippets for them, for free. Sigh.)

Comment: (Without `defer`, that is. :-) )